# How to use PHP to loop through MySQL result set with records grouped by decade?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

Let's say that I have a bunch of records in MySQL, something like this:

> ID | DATE       | TITLE
> 1  | 1961-03-21 | Cats
> 2  | 1964-02-05 | Dogs
> 3  | 1976-11-30 | Mice
> 4  | 1979-09-14 | Monkeys

What would you suggest as a way to pull all the records and echo each into a group of their decade? That is, I want them organized into even 10 years spans, kind of like this:

> 1960s
> record 1
> record 2
>
> 1970s
> record 3
> etc, etc

Ideally, it will only print out the "decade labels" if a record from that decade is actually present as well.

MySQL Group By doesn't seem right. What about a *while loop* with an embedded *if* test using some kind of math test against each year?

I'm struggling to come up with something elegant, scalable and reusable in the event I don't know which decades (or centuries) will be present.

============ UPDATE =============

Using the suggestion provided by Col Shrapnel, this is what I wrote. It does exactly what I need. (Could it be significantly more elegant?)

```
<?php
// perform Query, sort by date, get your results, then...
$lastDecade = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows->list))
{
    $currentYear = date("Y",strtotime($row['date']));
    $currentDecade = floor((int)$currentYear/10)*10;
    if($currentDecade>$lastDecade)
    {
        echo "<h1>" . $currentDecade . "</h1>";
        $lastDecade = $currentDecade;
    }
        echo "<h2>" . $row['title'] . "</h2>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your problem? how to get a decade from date or how to create such loop with an embedded if test?

Comment: I guess it's mostly the former. What's the most efficient way to get a decade. But also, how could I then loop through the results so that the records get grouped by those decades?

Comment: i hope you can get a year from date

Comment: Yes, I can get a year from a date. I can loop through results, embed an if within, test against variables etc.

Comment: I don't think you need `GROUP BY` here - just calculate the decade for each iteration and compare it with the previous one. When a change is detected, print a new decade row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get a decade from year you have to divide it by 10, floor it, and multiply back.

to save a current decade have a variable $last_decade and test it against current one (and then rewrite with current)

select your records ordered by date

that's all

Comment: Step one (getting the decade), makes sense. Thanks. But part two, I don't get. How does this group my records as in my output example, where a new heading is printed for each decade?

Comment: I think I can figure part 2 out with the guidance you provided. Thank you.

Comment: print your heading only at decade change. compare current with a previous one for that.

Comment: Thanks. I added the resulting code using your suggestion as an update to my original question.

Comment: you need to initialize $lastDecade though. if you don't it may contain unpredictable value and thus spoil the output.

Comment: Got it. Did away with some other redundancies as well.

Answer (score 1):

The column that you want to add is `truncate(year(from_unixtime(date))/10,0) as Decade`.   You then want to order by Decade as the major order key and in your fetch loop detect break on Decade.

(or omit the `from_unixtime()` is you are using MySQL dates rather than PHP ones.) E.g.

```
$sql = 'SELECT ID, DATE, TITLE,
               truncate(year(DATE)/10,0)*10 as DECADE
        FROM   ALBUM_TABLE 
        ORDER BY 4,3';
```

if you want to order by title within decade.  Why does this involve changing your schema??

If you want to order strictly by date, then doing this decade algo in PHP is probably easier, but is that what you want.  Can you think of a better way if you do want title order within decade?

Comment: I don't want to add any data or fields to my table if that's what you're suggesting. I want to do this on the fly using PHP.

Comment: ?? This doesn't add any fields to your table ??

Comment: it won't make any difference. you still need use PHP to group records

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel agreed that you'd still need to detect and process break of DECADE in your PHP fetch loop. Given that I said that in-PHP is easier for strict time order, how would _you_ do title within decide in PHP only without getting into extra sorts and loops.  So I disagree: it does make a difference in this case: the implementation is simpler and clearer.

Comment: why do you sort by both decade and date? does it make any difference?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel.  I've just notices my typo which is probably the source of this confusion I meant "4,3" not "4,2" which a good reason why we should use column names and not ordinals in ORDER BY clauses.  Thanks for pointing this out :-)